# How to generate rtpengine ICE-candidates in different IP families?

Tags: voip

I have rtpengine, which looking to internet with IPv4 and IPv6. And I want rtpengine to generate SDP like this:

```
a=candidate:1146808739 1 udp 2122262783 2a02:6b8::408:911a:cfea:88e5:1b82 62051 typ host generation 0 network-id 2
a=candidate:2666738149 1 udp 2122197247 2a02:6b8::408:b091:332b:eebc:7c3a 62052 typ host generation 0 network-id 6
a=candidate:1047344351 1 udp 2122129151 172.22.93.129 62053 typ host generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:2052615222 1 udp 2122063615 95.108.174.103 62054 typ host generation 0 network-id 4
a=candidate:1986380506 1 udp 2121998079 10.0.75.1 62055 typ host generation 0 network-id 5
a=candidate:181998931 1 tcp 1518283007 2a02:6b8::408:911a:cfea:88e5:1b82 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 2
a=candidate:3497053461 1 tcp 1518217471 2a02:6b8::408:b091:332b:eebc:7c3a 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 6
a=candidate:1894697007 1 tcp 1518149375 172.22.93.129 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 1
a=candidate:886804678 1 tcp 1518083839 95.108.174.103 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 4
a=candidate:954613290 1 tcp 1518018303 10.0.75.1 9 typ host tcptype active generation 0 network-id 5
```

But it generates only this:

```
a=candidate:cwn1crEfNlSJaOpo 1 UDP 2130706431 178.154.134.1 21174 typ host
a=candidate:cwn1crEfNlSJaOpo 2 UDP 2130706430 178.154.134.1 21175 typ host
```

Is it realy and how?

Answer (score 0):

As it said in documentation:

> It is possible to specify multiple addresses for the same logical
>   interface (the same name). Most commonly this would be one IPv4
>   addrsess and one IPv6 address, for example: --interface=192.168.63.1
>   --interface=fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0. In this example, no interface name is given, therefore both addresses will be added to a logical
>   interface named default. You would use the address family option to
>   tell rtpengine which address to use in a particular case.

and:

> It is possible to combine the BASE:SUFFIX notation with specifying
>   multiple addresses for the same interface name. An advanced example
>   could be (using config file notation, and omitting actual network
>   addresses):

```
interface = pub:1/IPv4 pub:1/IPv4 pub:1/IPv6 pub:2/IPv4 pub:2/IPv6 pub:3/IPv6 pub:4/IPv4
```

> In this example, when direction=pub is IPv4 is needed as a primary
>   address, either pub:1, pub:2, or pub:4 might be selected. When pub:1
>   is selected, one IPv4 and one IPv6 address will be used as additional
>   ICE alternatives. For pub:2, only one IPv6 is used as ICE alternative,
>   and for pub:4 no alternatives would be used. When IPv6 is needed as a
>   primary address, either pub:1, pub:2, or pub:3 might be selected. If
>   at any given time not enough ports are available on any interface, it
>   will not be selected by the round-robin algorithm.